# Android: Canvas.DrawBitmap VS Drawable.Draw - Huge performance boost

Tags: android

I just found out something and I was wondering about how and why.
I'm developing a small arcade game for Android. I decided to ignore OpenGL and use the standard SurfaceView and Drawables to do it, since it's suppose to be light (10 sprites or so).
I have drawables that I load, and I use the method Draw and passing them my canvas. This how every sprite is drawn to the screen.
Well it turns out that drawing 4-5 big sprites (200X400 or so) takes a long time on less-than-brand-new phone models. Long enough to make my game unplayable. We're talking about 50-60 milliseconds to draw a single frame using this method. And I really don't do anything there apart from drawing, nowhere I can cut costs. So I decided to try and use Bitmaps instead. Here, however, I need to pre-set the size, since there's no 'setBounds' method in a bitmap. No prob, I resize them to fit my current screen on load, problem solved.

OK. So I got bitmaps. I use Canvas.DrawBitmap now to draw. I bench the new draw method.. and I get a whooping **400% performance boost!** Instead of 50-60ms, the entire draw loop now takes 8-12ms. **What the hell??** 
To rule it out, I timed the setBounds too, it takes <1ms so it's not to blame. It's the actual Drawable.Draw that slows things down.

For me this is great news, since I really didn't want to learn OpenGL to make my game playable, but I can't stop wondering about it - Is it fine? are there problems with my method? Why isn't it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: This sounds great, but it could be nice to have the actual test code you ran to verify the results...

Answer (score 4):

The `SurfaceView` of your `Canvas` is meant to be used when you should iterate constantly and `Drawable` is not for that purpose.

Comment: It's the same canvas object I use, either canvas.drawBitmap or Drawable.Draw(canvas). In both cases it's a canvas derived from the SurfaceView, so eitehr way it's surfaceView that you're working with.
You don't need to choose between Drawabls and SurfaceView - You use Drawables *with* SurfaceView. This is how Google's 'fast game' (lunar lander for instance) code samples work.

Answer (score 2):

`Canvas.drawBitmap` is doing a lot less work than `Drawable.draw` so it is faster.

### `Drawable.draw`

Since [`Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) is an abstract class, let's look at [`BitmapDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html):

[*BitmapDrawable.draw(canvas)*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java#478)

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapState.mBitmap;
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return;
    }
    final BitmapState state = mBitmapState;
    final Paint paint = state.mPaint;
    if (state.mRebuildShader) {
        final Shader.TileMode tmx = state.mTileModeX;
        final Shader.TileMode tmy = state.mTileModeY;
        if (tmx == null && tmy == null) {
            paint.setShader(null);
        } else {
            paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                    tmx == null ? Shader.TileMode.CLAMP : tmx,
                    tmy == null ? Shader.TileMode.CLAMP : tmy));
        }
        state.mRebuildShader = false;
    }
    final int restoreAlpha;
    if (state.mBaseAlpha != 1.0f) {
        final Paint p = getPaint();
        restoreAlpha = p.getAlpha();
        p.setAlpha((int) (restoreAlpha * state.mBaseAlpha + 0.5f));
    } else {
        restoreAlpha = -1;
    }
    final boolean clearColorFilter;
    if (mTintFilter != null && paint.getColorFilter() == null) {
        paint.setColorFilter(mTintFilter);
        clearColorFilter = true;
    } else {
        clearColorFilter = false;
    }
    updateDstRectAndInsetsIfDirty();
    final Shader shader = paint.getShader();
    final boolean needMirroring = needMirroring();
    if (shader == null) {
        if (needMirroring) {
            canvas.save();
            // Mirror the bitmap
            canvas.translate(mDstRect.right - mDstRect.left, 0);
            canvas.scale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, mDstRect, paint);
        if (needMirroring) {
            canvas.restore();
        }
    } else {
        updateShaderMatrix(bitmap, paint, shader, needMirroring);
        canvas.drawRect(mDstRect, paint);
    }
    if (clearColorFilter) {
        paint.setColorFilter(null);
    }
    if (restoreAlpha >= 0) {
        paint.setAlpha(restoreAlpha);
    }
}
```

You can see that it even calls `canvas.drawBitmap` internally.

### `Canvas.drawBitmap`

Compare that to `Canvas.drawBitmap`. It is much shorter.

[*Canvas.drawBitmap*](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#L1335)

```
public void drawBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, @Nullable Paint paint) {
    throwIfCannotDraw(bitmap);
    native_drawBitmap(mNativeCanvasWrapper, bitmap, left, top,
            paint != null ? paint.getNativeInstance() : 0, mDensity, mScreenDensity, bitmap.mDensity);
}
```

There are a few different `drawBitmap` methods but all of them are shorter than the `Drawable.draw` method. Watch out for traps [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628193/how-to-draw-bitmap-fast-in-ondraw-method-in-canvas-android) to keep your bitmap drawing fast.