# How to draw Bitmap fast in onDraw() method in canvas android

Tags: android, dictionary, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to draw a marker on single tap method in android. when i draw the marker it will draw but it will take more time to draw i.e 30-40 milliseconds some times it takes 2-3 seconds. Here is my code for class in which i have draw method.

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
            ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean arg2) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, arg2);

        // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        // ---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_darkblue);
        Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_green);
        Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_bue);
        Bitmap bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_light);
        Bitmap bmp4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_light);
        Bitmap bmp5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_light);
        Bitmap bmp6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_light);
        if (count == 1) {
            int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 0);
            switch (caller) {
            case R.id.btMap:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp1.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp2.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton3:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp3.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton4:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp4, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp4.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton5:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp5, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp5.recycle();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton6:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp6, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
                bmp6.recycle();
                break;
            }
        }
        // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        // R.drawable.pin_annotation_green);
        // if (count == 1) {
        // canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
        // }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should initialize all bitmaps in Constructor. Decoding bitmap takes a long time. You can use a `HashMap` (key, value) to store them. Then in onDraw, get the matched bitmap and draw it directly.

For example

```
public class MyView extends View{

    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> mStore = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 0);
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        switch (caller) {
        case R.id.btMap:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.btMap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton1);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp1.recycle();
            bmp1 = null;
            break;
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void init() {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_darkblue);
        mStore.put(R.id.btMap, bmp);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pin_annotation_green);
        mStore.put(R.id.imageButton1, bmp);
    }
}
```

Here is what I've done based on your code. You have to check some duplicated resource IDs.

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> mStore = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
        ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
    super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_darkblue);
    mStore.put(R.id.btMap, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_green);
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton1, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_bue);
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton2, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_light); 
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton3, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_light); // check it
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton4, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_light); // check it
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton5, bmp);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pin_annotation_light); // check it
    mStore.put(R.id.imageButton6, bmp);

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean arg2) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, arg2);

    // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

    // ---add the marker---
    if (count == 1) {
        int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 0);
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        switch (caller) {
        case R.id.btMap:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.btMap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton1);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton2);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton3);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton4:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton4);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton5:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton5);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton6:
            bmp = mStore.get(R.id.imageButton6);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            break;
        }
    }
    // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    // R.drawable.pin_annotation_green);
    // if (count == 1) {
    // canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
    // }
}
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40102/discussion-between-gaurav-kumar-and-yushulx)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. But I don't think you need the switch in the first example. Just do this: `int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 0);
        Bitmap bmp = mStore.get(caller);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
            break;
        }`

Answer (score 8):

The idea to optimize your code is to perform only the operations necessary for drawing. So you, should remove from your onDraw method :

- any instanciation : they take a long time, onDraw is called often and you don't want to create so many new objects. Store screenPts during onLayout and reuse the same points, always.
- BitmapFactory.decodeResource : this takes quite a long time. Decode your bitmap first, store them and only draw them during onDraw.
- recycle the bitmaps when you don't need them any more, not each time you drew them.

For instance :

- decode your bitmaps during onResume
- recycle them during onPause
- decoding should occur inside an async task. When the async task is over, raise a flag to indicate to onDraw that images are ready and can be drawn.
- it's very important to decode images in background as it takes a long time. Do not do this in main UI Thread. Otherwise your app will look unresponsive
- calculate your screenPts inside onLayout and reuse the same points all the time.
- don't call getIntent during onDraw either.

Briefly, minimize the operations during onDraw and you will achieve very fast drawing, around 60 FPS.

You should also consider removing that (ugly) switch and use an hashmap to associate the values of count and the bitmap to draw. An array would even be faster and maybe more appropriate here.

Comment: @gaurav kumar I think the above answer is complete and dont think any code is required. First you try to understand activity life cycle then you can easily apply above things. You should understand how many times which method and when it will be called. Then try to reuse your code and always use threads or async tasks(recommended in Android) to remove heavy code from UI threads and you are done. Concept given by "Snicolas" is very generic and can be applied on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove all `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` calls from your `draw()` method. Decode bitmap only once and keep reference to it. Then just call `canvas.drawBitmap()` in your `draw()` method.