# Draw bitmap on canvas by "onTouchListener" at specific position

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I use `Canvas` to draw `bitmap` by touch screen but they don't show bitmap on apps.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public LinearLayout screenlayout;

    public void draw (int x, int y){
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dam);                     
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(b);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

       final LinearLayout screenlayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screenlayout);
        screenlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        draw(x,y);                       

                        break; 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        break; 
                    } 
                    return true;          
                   } 
            });              
    }             
 }
```

Comment: where is your setContentView method in onCreate ? And how you are initializing the screenlayout ?

Comment: I edited as you comment.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628193/how-to-draw-bitmap-fast-in-ondraw-method-in-canvas-android

Answer (score 0):

As Ganpat Kaliya answer, I provide another code to solve this problem. Thanks to Ganpat Kaliya.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static float vtx;
public static float vty;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Test view = new Test(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float a = event.getX();
            float b = event.getY();

            vtx=a;
            vty=b;
            v.invalidate();
            return true; 
        } 
    });

}
```

}

And:

public class Test extends View {

```
public Test(Context context) {
    super(context); 
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    float x=MainActivity.vtx;
    float y=MainActivity.vty;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);

    canvas.drawLine(10,10,50,50,paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawLine(50, 50, 90, 10, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 3, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,10,paint);        

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dam);                     
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);

}
```

}